# Rails: Unable to overwrite config.action_cable.url

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, actioncable

I am trying to over write the `config.action_cable.url` to something like this `config.action_cable.url=wss://test.domain.com/staging/cable`

but when i load my application i still see error message `WebSocket connection to wss://test.domain.com/cable`

Any thoughts on how i can do this would be really great.
Thanks.